# Apache redirect for Get call to some other server node

Tags: apache

How can I do a get API call, to redirect to another sever in Apache using htaccess, or any other configuration?

I want to use some other server to process my requests to get more performance, without changing my application logic.

i.e : i have following:

```
 localhot/user/getInformation to 192.169.1.1/user/getinformation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/user/getInformation http://192.168.1.1/user/getInformation [NC,L,R=301]
```

This will do a `permanent redirect (301)` from `/user/getInformation` to `http://192.168.1.1/user/getInformation`.